# Thread class constructor in Java equivalent to Thread class constructor in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, stack-overflow

This Java Thread constructor takes 3 arguments. C# Thread constructor takes max two arguments:

> Initializes a new instance of the Thread class, specifying a delegate
>   that allows an object to be passed to the thread when the thread is
>   started and specifying the maximum stack size for the thread.

My question is what's the equivalent of this Java code in C# so I could avoid stack overflow issues?

```
new Thread(null, new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        new SomeClass().run();
                    } catch(IOException e) {
                    }
                }
            }, "1", 1 << 26).start();
```

Comment: The default maximum stack size should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pure C# equivalent would be

```
var thread = new Thread(() => {
        try
        {
            new SomeClass().Run();
        }
        catch(IOException)
        {
        }
    }, 1 << 26);
thread.Name = "1";
thread.Start();
```

However it is extreemly rare to ever need to modify the stack size in C#. See the [following documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cykbwz4(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) in the constructor we are calling for the above code.

> #### Remarks
>
> Avoid using this constructor overload. The default
>   stack size used by the Thread(ThreadStart) constructor overload is the
>   recommended stack size for threads. If a thread has memory problems,
>   the most likely cause is programming error, such as infinite
>   recursion.

You can try the much simpler expression.

```
Task.Run(() => new SomeClass().Run());
```

Because you are not observing the exceptions of the thread anyway in your old code it does not matter if you catch IOException or not.